# How to remove the pop info window in Google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

An empty info window is showing in my map . I don't know how to remove that. Someone help me out of this.

[image]

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"> </script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey"></script>
<script>
            $(document).on("pageinit", "#map-page", function() {
            i=0;
            setInterval(function(){
            if(i=="0"){
             getcurrentlatlong();}
             i++;
            },2000);               


            });

            function getcurrentlatlong(){
                if (navigator.geolocation)
                {              
                //  //alert("navigator.geolocation is supported");
                  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy:true });
                                                //enableHighAccuracy:true means if network not enable then it ask for GPS
                }
                else{
                    //alert("Please Switch ON your GPS ");
                }
            }

            function onSuccess(position) { 
              // enable ur gps, it takes sometime to call till now wait   
               // //alert("onSuccess called");
                var image = 'http://temp.pickzy.com/phonegap/car.png';
                var lat=position.coords.latitude;
                var longi=position.coords.longitude;
               // //alert("latitude is: "+lat+ " longitude is: "+ longi);

                 mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi),
                 myOptions = {
                     zoom:16,
                     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                     center: mapCenter,
                 },
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions),

                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi),
                     map: map,
                     icon: image,
                     title:"hi",
                     });

                        $('#latiLong').val("("+lat+","+longi+")");

                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
                        var blueCoords = [
                        {lat:1.346414, lng:103.873662},
                        {lat:1.347347, lng:103.873662},
                        {lat:1.347655, lng:103.874402},
                        {lat:1.346828, lng:103.874491},
                        {lat:1.346544,lng:103.874343},
                        {lat:1.346291,lng: 103.874295}
                        ];

                        var redCoords = [
                        {lat: 1.298977,lng: 103.845774},
                        {lat: 1.299176,lng: 103.845690},
                        {lat: 1.299438,lng: 103.845833},
                        {lat: 1.299351,lng: 103.846338},
                        {lat: 1.298831,lng: 103.846031}

        ];

            // Construct a draggable red triangle with geodesic set to true.
          new google.maps.Polygon({
          map: map,
          paths: redCoords,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          draggable: false,
          geodesic: true
        });

        // Construct a draggable blue triangle with geodesic set to false.
        new google.maps.Polygon({
          map: map,
          paths: blueCoords,
          strokeColor: '#0000FF',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#0000FF',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          draggable: false,
          geodesic: false
        });
            }

            function onError(error)
            {
               alert("Getting the error"+error.code + "\nerror mesg :" +error.message);
            }
            </script>
```

Above is my code what i need to add in this to remove the pop up from the google map.

Please help me .

Comment: Remove the `infoWindow`

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your code:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because I was passing `{map: map}` to a new `InfoWindow` just as you are. When I removed that, it finally had the behavior I wanted which was only showing an `InfoWindow` when calling [open](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow) where you can specify the map and an optional anchor, such as a `Marker`.

I'm not sure why I was even doing that in the first place. The `map` key is not listed as one of the [InfoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindowOptions), nor is it shown in [their example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#open), which is where I thought I first got started, but maybe I saw some other example. It would appear that you can still set the map for the `InfoWindow` in this way, but it is clearly not preferable unless you set the content at the same time.